# Add Geometry of Connector Shape programmatically

Tags: c#, visio, office-addins, visio2013

I create shape and connectors with C# but I want to set Geometry of connectors (I mean lineTo, MoveTo) by code too.

I tried this code but it raise: `This section type does  not support named rows`

```
short iRow = (short)(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowVertex);
short visTagLineTo = (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisRowTags.visTagLineTo;
var aa = newShape.get_Section(1);
short sectionId = (short)(newShape.AddSection(
    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionFirstComponent));
var row = newShape.AddNamedRow(sectionId, "LineTo", visTagLineTo);
```

Actually I don't know how to get the `Geometry1` section.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the misleading user interface in the shapesheet window, geometry rows are not named rows.  Try `newShape.AddRow(sectionId, rowIndex, visTagLineTo)` instead.

Comment: when I use newShape.AddRow(sectionId, rowIndex, visTagLineTo) then I can set cell value with newShape.get_CellsSRC(sectionId, 0, 3).FormulaU    but nothing changes in the result. It seems that I should change more related cells.